# Run python script in a directory

Tags: python, path

Let's say I have a script `script.py` that's in directory `A/`. I also have directory `B/`, which has files that the script uses, and expects to be in its working directory.

I also have a Python source `starter.py` in directory `A/`, which needs to `Popen` the command `python script.py` so that when the script is running, it'll have a working directory of `B/`.

To be more specific, I have

```
blah/A/
- starter.py
- script.py
blah/B/
- data-file.txt
- more-data.blah
```

and `starter.py` has some code

```
Popen(["python", "script.py"])
```

How can I change the starter script so that `script.py` will be able to access the data files in `B/`?

The only solution I thought of was to compute the relative path between the data directory and the directory of `script.py` -- that is, `A/` and `B/` respectively, which would give a relative directory of `../A/`, and then to change the `Popen` call so that it uses the relative directory and `B/` as the working directory:

```
Popen(["python", "relative/path/to/script.py"], cwd="absolute/path/to/data/")
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: If `blah/A` is in your `PATH` environment variable, then there is no need to specify where the scripts are.  Equally, you could use your own environment variable to set the name of the data directory then use `os.environ` in your calling script.

Comment: I don't want to have to change the PATH to do this. Besides, do changes to that even "percolate" to `Popen` calls?

Comment: Yes, environment variables are copied from parent to child. `Popen` will use `$PATH`.    If you don't wish to alter `PATH` then use your own environment variable.  BTW, which OS/shell are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, so `cmd` is the shell. I don't understand how I can change PATH so that `Popen(["python", "script.py"], cwd='B/')` will still work from directory `B/`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Several ways to do that.  Altering environment variables on Windows is a bit of a pain.  https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml You could also use `set` from `cmd.exe`.  On Windows a number of directories are searched first, including the current directory (not on Linux/UNIX/OS X).  If it still isn't found, then the directories in `%path%` are searched from left to right.

Comment: An alternative to using environment variables is to pass directory names on the command-line to the calling script (`sys.argv`), defaulting to the current directory.

Comment: @cdarke I like that idea more that modifying PATH. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was suggested in the comments to the question, why not pass the directory containing the input files as a command line argument to `script.py`?
So you can do:

```
Popen(["python", "relative/path/to/script.py", "absolute/path/to/data/"])
```

Your absolute path can also be something like `../B/`